# Non-tirivial Ideal in a Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be the maximal ideal in $R$, i.e., $I$ is a proper ideal in $R$ which is not contained in another proper ideal in $R$. Then, the book that I study claims that the quotient ring $R/I$ cannot have a nontrivial ideal. The trivial ideals are zero ideal and $R$ itself. I would appreciate if you can help me understand why the above claim is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

> Correspondence theorem:
>
> For a surjective (commutative, unital) ring homomorphism $\psi:R\to S$, the map $X\mapsto\psi(X)$ defines a bijection between ideals of $R$ containing $\ker\psi$ and ideals of $S$.

Comment: Thank for your help, but this is too abstract for me. I need a more elementary explanation.

Comment: @bc78 Consider the quotient homomorphism $q:R\twoheadrightarrow R/I$. You want to understand ideals in the RHS, the correspondence tells you how to relate these with ideals in the LHS. A proof of the correspondence theorem can be found in, say, Artin, but it is not especially difficult

Answer (score 0):

By the correspondence theorem,  ideals in $\mathcal R/\mathscr I$ correspond to ideals in $\mathcal R$ containing $\mathscr I$.

But since $\mathscr I$ is *maximal*, there are no such ideals.

Comment: This is the same as my answer (posted an hour before) but gives the entire game away, rather than leaving it as a hint (it's also misleading since there *are* ideals in $R$ containing $I$)